# How to get position of finger with leap motion. More specifically, how to detect when finger touches edge of HTML5 canvas

Tags: leap-motion

I am trying to do some web work and am utilizing leap motion. Does anyone know how to detect when you are touching the edge of the HTML5 canvas you are working in? And if so do you also know how to grab and store that data?

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a mapping between the 3D, real-world coordinate system of the Leap and the 2D, pixel coordinate system of the web page or canvas object. You could, for example, decide that one real-world millimeter equals one pixel and that you are going to ignore the Leap's Z-axis. Then if a finger is 200mm to the right of the origin, then that could mean that the corresponding position on the HTML canvas is 200 pixels to the right of the center of the image.

See https://developer.leapmotion.com/documentation/skeletal/javascript/devguide/Leap_Coordinate_Mapping.html for more information on this topic.

As for getting the 3D finger position in the first place:
* Get a Frame object
* Get a Finger object from the Frame
* Get the tipPosition from the Finger

You will also have to decide when a finger qualifies as touching at all.